# staggeredgridview implementation help in android

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I'm newbie to android and must use image as Pinterest. i am using staggeredgridview using etsy demo but as soon as project is imported to eclipse it shows many errors is there any step to implement staggered demo?

Comment: You are not clear enough about your errors. No one can figure out what's wrong in your code if you don't give atleast minimum information.

Comment: Please Mention your  Log Cat for Errors.. So that we will try to answer you correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below code..

https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView

Hope Help you.

Answer (score 2):

if the Existing Code is Correct, and It shows An error when you import the Project You need to Take Care of two things..

If you want to seed Demo... if a Existing Projects... it Depends on the **Way You Import.**

**1.Some Existing Source codes can Be imported directly..**
Like :

```
File> 
Import > 
Android >
Existing Android Code Into Work Space> Browse file..
```

But For Some Source Code In the Above Way you will Get Errors Definitely.. Due to incomplete Import..(I mean Eclipse may not import Complete Functionality)

***`If you Get Errors in First Way choose Second Way..`***

**2.Second Way to Import**

```
File> 
other> 
Android >
Android project from Existing Code> Browse file..
```

I hope this is Problem..
Or Else Please Mention Your Log Cat Code so that the Error will be Fixed..

**Update**

One More thing If you are Using Android Build Tools.. It may a problem for some old codes..

So you need to Use Separate Eclipse J2EE kepler IDE and Android SDK ...

See here for [Reference](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)...

One Place Your Log Cat.. I will Solve Problem...

Comment: i did as u told but still i get error saying class missing for etsy demo

Comment: i tried and its working fine but my client want it same as etsy and when i import it shows StaggeredGridEmptyViewActivity.java class not found and many other class missign

Comment: you mean its working fine but some other classes missing.. Right..  please import New Code weather which way works fine for you...

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'column_count' in 
  package 'com.etsy.android.sample'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'item_margin' in 
  package 'com.etsy.android.sample'

Comment: The following classes could not be found:
- com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView

Comment: is this things happen when you import the project.. in any first or second way.. But its Worked fine When i go through this url...https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid and imported project in second way,,,

Comment: 2nd way is file->new->other->Android Project from Existing Codes->browse... rite?

Comment: ya right now i am checking here every thing is fine.. all classes are there.. i am using eclipse(j2EE) kepler and android latest SDK not android Build tools eclipse... if Its works dont forget to upvote and Tick right..

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this [link](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Pinterest-Style+Staggered+Masonry+List+in+Android):

It explains few steps as follows:

1. Just Use a Grid List
2. Try a Modified GridView with Staggered Grid View
3. Try a Modified List with Pinterest Like Adapter View
4. Or Try Two Synced List Views with Pinterest List View

Comment: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'. i m getting dis error in res/values/styles.xml

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

You might not have change your Package Name or i would be good if you have posted error.